# How webpack reads what to import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I was wondering and trying to find out how webpack internally finds out which are the import statements a entry file has?

For example my `index.js` looks like

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import Loading from 'components/Loading';
import Button from 'components/Button';
import Header from 'components/Header';
import Footer from 'components/Footer';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="shopping-list">
                <Header />
                <h1>Shopping List for {this.props.name}</h1>
                <ul>
                   <li>Instagram</li>
                   <li>WhatsApp</li>
                   <li>Oculus</li>
                </ul>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

Now I am trying to understand how webpack is finding out what are the other imports that file has? And then one of the imported files has other imported files?

Comment: I don't know the implementation details, but it's definitely some kind of a graph traversal with your entry file as the source vertex. Also, see [this](https://github.com/ronami/minipack) to understand how a bundler works.

Comment: AST traversion recursively from your entry point/points.

Comment: You should start at https://webpack.js.org/concepts/ to get a high level understanding and explore the links they provide for detailed explanation, if you do not understand that then you lack knowledge of more fundamental concepts so you need to learn that first.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, Webpack is build tool and it is design to convert your app into optimized solution like compressing the js/scss/css and many more files.

Webpack can be configurable according to your choice and there are many loaders and plugins developed, you can use them to add support for that type of file.

It's like telling a system to take list of source files (input) and compiling them by using related webpack plugin or loader and giving optimized solution as output.

by webpack configuration, you tell it that load this type of file and generate output here and it normally convert your advanced source code to native source code so, it can work on any system.

for example,

we know that scss file is not supported by browsers, we need to convert it into css and then we can import it, but using scss loader plugin and by configuring it with webpack you can directly use scss file no need to manually convert scss to css and directly can import scss file into component and webpack will read the file, see the type and convert it for us.

configuring the webpack is the difficult part but there are pretty good pre-configured solution available to use like [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) where you don't need to worry about the configurations

for more info see the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts)

Comment: I understand what you saying but I am still not clear how webpack does it, reads the file and find out the import statements. I am more of trying to understand the implementation

Comment: Basically import is not part of webpack, it is part of es6 feature and webpack compiles it using the babel plugin and convert it into normal js code that browser can understand but for that webpack is needs to be configured to use babel plugin for that kind of file.

import is used for using functionality from another file which is exported from that file using export statement.

for more details [see this blog](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/a-simple-intro-to-javascript-imports-and-exports-389dd53c3fac)